# "another house moving" OR "another moving house"

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

Imagine you see someone is moving house in your street, and a few days later you see someone else who is also moving house. And a few days later, when you look out of window, you see another one, and you are suprised.

So when you look out of the window and see such a situaton, would you say:

**"Another house moving!"** or **"Another moving house!"**

Comment: Although we do talk about 'someone moving house', your examples sound as though the house itself is moving! You might say "Another house **move**!" or "Another family moving house!"

Comment: @KateBunting, Thank you very much. That is what I need, "A house-move."

Comment: Both options in the title bring to mind [this](https://www.wolfehousebuildingmovers.com).

Comment: As pointed out in comments to the accepted answer by @Hearth , the standard answer here is going to differ between British and American dialects.

Comment: if anything, it would be MOVE, never MOVING

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general:

We normally just say: “Another move”.

Generally, we don't use the word *house* to talk about moving.

> A: We moved here last year.
> B: When did you move here?
> B: Was your move difficult?

See? No *house* at all. :)

Response: *Oh, were you moving to a new house or apartment?*

That said, we do also say colloquially: “We moved houses last year.”

Meaning: from one house to another.

Comment: Also, "*we moved house*" is common - where "house" indicates the contents of the house rather than the physical building.

Comment: @freedomn-m I believe "we moved house" is much more common in BrE than in AmE. Most Americans would just say "we moved", or "we moved to a new house" if more context was needed.

Comment: @freedomn-m "moved house" is very much a Britishism. In AmE you just say "moved". I'm not familiar with other dialects enough to say what they would use.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I really see no need to put the sentences like that. I want the person to read them straight across.

Comment: In AmE you can also say "changed houses".

Comment: @Barmar One **Could** say "changed houses" in US English, but at least in my experience hardly anyone ever does. The verb is almost always "moved".

Answer (score 11):

If you say "another house moving" or "another moving house", it seems to imply that the house itself is moving.

I would say "another house move".

Comment: agreed on the 2nd one, but punctuation matters on the 1st. "another house, moving", yes. but "another house-moving" works just fine.

Comment: Not to a US ear it doesn't. I don't think i have **ever** heard "*house move*" or "*moving house*"  except in a UK setting, or when the speaker was (or was supposed to be) English, or at least British.

Answer (score 7):

I would say "someone else is moving in" or "someone else is moving out."

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem with both these options is the only actor is the house, so it makes it look like it is the house that is moving (as others have said).

> house(noun/actor) moving (verb)
> moving (verb) house(noun/actor)

to use this construct you need to add an actor into the sentence so family, person, couple etc. This can then turn "moving house" into the verb

> the Jones (noun/actor) are moving house(verb)
> another family (noun/actor) are moving house(verb)
> more people (noun/actor) are moving (verb)

Answer (score 2):

There is a US/British difference here, and I think it is worth having in the answers rather than just the comments.

> UK: "We moved house last year." (See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/move), for instance.)

> US: "We moved last year."

Based on that, and on the comments, you then have these options:

> UK: "Look - another house-move."

> US: "Look - another move."

Apologies for using a US dictionary to document a British usage, but it makes it clearer that it's not used in the US.

Answer (score 0):

### UK vs US usage

As several com,metns and answers have mentioned "*Move house*" (meaning to relocate, or change residence) is an idiom, or largely British use. A US audience is likely to think that either of

> - Another house moving!
> - Another moving house!

refers to a housed physically moving

#### Sources

- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/move_house) defines this as:

> (*idiomatic, UK*) To change one's place of residence. *I haven’t got any mail since I(’ve) moved house.*

- [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/moving+house) states that "*move house*" is an idiom:

> To relocate from one house or place of residence to another. Primarily heard in UK. *We only moved house last spring, but because of Pete's new job, we're going to have to do it again next month!*

##### Conflating Usage

While the Google Ngram (liked in a section below) does sow a significant frequency for "*move  house*" on inspection of the supporting Google Books query, it appars that many, perhaps most are actually for MOVE house. This refers to an organization known as MOVE which had a house in Philadelphia, Pennsylvania *in the US). In 1985 they became involved in a confrontation and armed standoff with the police, and the Philadelphia police dropped two bombs on the house. The Philadelphia Fire Department allowed the fire to burn, and some 61 houses were destroyed.  The incident attracted national attention, and is referred to in many publications. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1985_MOVE_bombing for details. The frequency of references to this incident probably skews the google Ngram results to some extent.

### Word Order

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-norwegian/move-house) lists "**move house**" giving a definition of:

> to change one’s home or place of residence; *They’re moving house next week.*

It does not give any entry of "*move-house*", "*house move*" any form with "moving".

[Sentencedict](https://sentencedict.com/move%20house.html) shows many examples with "move house" and none with "house move".

[This](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=move+house%2Cmoving+house%2Chouse+move%2Chouse+moving%2Chouse-move&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) Google Ngram shows "moving house" to be the most frequent form in the British English corpus, followed closely  by "move house". The forms "house move" and "house moving" are shown with much lower frequency. The other corpus choices show generally simialr results.

However, thje uses found via the related Google Books search seem to show "*moving house* used to describe a process, as a verb form: "*we are moving house*". Ngrams shows not enough examples with "another" to plot.

### Conclusion

I am not a native speaker of UK or British English, although I have read quite a bit of it. Based on the sources above and my experience, I would favor one of

> - Another house move
> - Someone else is moving house

for the situation in the question.